# Data-name (dataset) attribute not reported correctly

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, dataset

I created a custom dataset attribute on an element node (El.dataset.FTid=i;), where i is a number, but when I use (El.attributes) to look at it, the attribute name is reported as (data--f-tid) instead of (data-FTid) as expected. Very strange! Firefox 63.0.3 (64bit).

Answer (score 1):

When setting properties of the `dataset` collection of a DOM element, they will automatically be converted to the corresponding attribute names following [these rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Name_conversion):

> camelCase to dash-style: The opposite transformation, that maps a key
>   to an attribute name, uses the following rules:
>
> Restriction:
>
> - A dash must not be immediately followed by an ASCII
>     lowercase letter a to z (before the transformation);
> - a prefix data- is
>     added;
> - any ASCII uppercase letter A to Z is transformed into a dash
>     followed by its lowercase counterpart;
> - other characters are left
>     unchanged.

In your case, you should probably use:

```
El.dataset.ftId = i;
```

which will be accessible via:

```
El.getAttribute('data-ft-id')
```

Comment: My comment got auto-erased. I said that I tried lowercasing the attribute in my JavaScript code and it worked perfectly. The documentation I used did not describe this. Yes, I did forget that all HTML attributes are case-insensitive.

Comment: @DavidSpector I believe your comment was on the other answer (that got deleted). That person was completely right in that attributes are case-insentitive. However, you are allowed to use uppercase characters when setting values into the `dataset` collection (they'll be converted), as explained in this answer.

Comment: I would have chosen a different design, since attributes are case-insensitive: I would have silently converted any upper-case characters to lower case. Any high-end developer could invent their own scheme for representing uppercase chars if they wanted.

Comment: @DavidSpector Yeah this is not the most intuitive thing in the world. The idea is that properties and variable names in JS are, by convention (not sure it's a written convention though), in camelCase, while HTML data- attributres values are separeted-by-dashes. So transforming them into one another kinda makes sense. Btw, consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped.